# Flush delayed frames every a few input frames in x264

Tags: h.264, x264

Hi I am new to x264 and know some basics. The encoding API routine used in x264 cli (x264.c) is summarized as:

1. call `x264_encoder_open` and set up parameters.
2. fetch a frame from input video and encode it with `x264_encoder_encode`.
3. iterate 2. until input EOF or the given frame limit is reached.
4. flush delayed frames.

**My problem** is: other than flush x264 encoder only once at the end of encoding process, is it possible or not to flush the delayed frames within step 2? For example, I want to flush the encoder manually every 20 frames (or a GOP frames) fed into `x264_encoder_encode` and resume the normal process when all delayed frames are encoded. Thus as a result the video will have several flush procedures.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. As once you send your first NULL-frame to x264_encoder_encode to flush frames it will stop all working threads for encoding so you will need to call x264_encoder_close/x264_encoder_open to start new encoding instance. Btw why you need to flush frames every 20 frames? Because I can't understand such use case.

Comment: I want to let the the caller of x264 APIs knows whether a number of frames has been encoded or not and I thought flush frames is a way dong this. Can you name another way? Maybe checking the id of output nal packet?

Comment: If you only want to know the number of frames already encoded you can simply calc the number of times x264_encoder_encode returned with >0 result. If you want know if some specific frame (after reordering) was already encoded you can check i_pts of pic_out.

Comment: Thanks! I have two more questions: 1. is x264_encoder_encode an asynchronized function, i.e., there are still x264 threads doing encoding jobs after x264_encoder_encode returns? 2. does x264_encoder_encode output one single encoded frame per time if ret value is > 0?

Comment: 1. Yes, if x264 was configured to use more than 1 thread (it is by default if you didn't set it explicitly to 1) and not use sliced-threads. But wouldn't use term async (for me async mean that we don't know when operation will be done and have callback to signal it) for this because x264_encoder_encode by itself is synchronous but actual encoding job can be done parallel to other work. 2. Yes, single x264_encoder_encode outputs only single encoded frame (or none frames at start). Return value <0 - mean error, 0 - mean none frame (delayed), >0 frame encoded (size of all NALs)